# Unsure how to continuously train a churn model after my model has gone live

Tags: forecasting, validation, churn

I'm having trouble describing this properly so I'll provide as many details as possible. First, here are a few details on the model that I am building:

- I have built a classification model that identifies whether or not my customer will request to leave in the next 2 months.
- I am using LIME to extract customer level drivers.
- Validation Strategy:

  - training data: Months T-13 to T-1
  - test data: Month T (current month)
- My sales team will then use these results to reach out and prevent our customers from leaving our product.

My question:

- My **continuous training strategy** was to use a sliding window approach to constantly train and with the most recent data and continue to predict the current month. I'll also use the previous train and test set to tune my hyperparameters.
- Since, our results will technically tamper with our training datasets moving forward, will this cause issues if we tune our model on post-launch data?
- Does this continuous training strategy make sense. Would this work after we've launched?

I'm more than happy to answer any clarifying questions. This is something I'm not 100% sure of and would love to learn more about.

Let me know if there are any

Comment: "Since, our results will technically tamper with our training datasets moving forward, will this cause issues if we tune our model on post-launch data?" - yes, this could be a problem. I don't have specific experience in churn modeling but I imagine that whether it is something to worry about (and how to fix it, if so) depends on the features you're using and how exactly the churn model is being applied in practice. What is the business doing with the outcome of the churn model and how will that tamper with future churn data?

Comment: Well the take the customers who are likely to churn and the drivers and use that when they have their monthly calls with the customers. I guess I would want to add features that are influenced by the usage of the model outputs, right?